# Bar chart fails to align

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I'd like to make a bar chart with two basic conditions:

- Each bar has a name (not a numeric value)
- Each bar has its own color

I tried the following, but the result is terribly off. What am I missing?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in, paperheight=3.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\geometry{left=0mm, right=3mm,top=6mm, bottom=3mm,}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar,
        xmin=0,
        symbolic y coords = {cat1, cat2, cat3}]

        \addplot [fill=red] coordinates {(1,cat1)};
        \addplot [fill=green] coordinates {(2,cat2)};
        \addplot [fill=blue] coordinates {(3,cat3)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To avoid the "shifting" of the bars add `bar shift=0pt` and to avoid the "repeating" axis labels add `ytick distance=1` to the `axis` options.

Comment: May I ask why you want to have each bar have its own color? In my opinion this is only useful when color would give another/additional information. That means, in your given example this is totally unnecessary. (But if you really want to/need to have the different colors, you have to use one `\addplot` command per color, as you already did in your example.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @StefanPinnow. Please post it as an answer and if it works I will accept it. The reason is that the scale shows criticality. Everywhere in my document, _redder=more critical_ and _greener=less critical_. The actual graph I'm building should show how many items are rated on each criticality level. Color is indeed redundant with the y-labels, but it would look weird to have that one graph that breaks the color scheme.

Comment: Update: I tried the solution above and it works. Thanks!